# Beautiful Soup, conditionally extracting Href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

From a given selection of webpages, I am trying to extract links from a table, conditional on the "document type" information being something specific. For example, on this website, I only want to get the Href if the document type is "Technical Assistance Reports".

[image]

When I use google to inspect it, I see this:

[image]

But When I use BeautifulSoup, I can find the Href but I am unable to find the text that says "Technical Assistance Reports".

```
import requests
url2 = "https://www.adb.org/projects/54128-001/main#project-documents"
response = requests.get(url2)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
#print(soup.prettify())
parent = soup.find_all('tr')
parent[1].find_all('td')
```

I get this:

```
[<td>
 <a href="/projects/documents/reg-54128-001-tar">Implementing the Cities Development Initiative for Asia: Technical Assistance Report</a> </td>,
 <td class="width-2-12 views-field views-field-field-date-content">
 <span class="date-display-single" content="2020-09-30T00:00:00+08:00" datatype="xsd:dateTime" property="">Sep 2020</span> </td>]
```

The Href is there and the date is there but I can't find the text "Technical Assistance Reports". The middle "td" isn't showing up.

This example only has the one document listed on the webpage but other examples may have many or none. Ideally, I would like to be able loop through all the "tr" and only pick up the Href if the document type is "Technical Assistance Report" or other stuff that I am looking for. What am I doing wrong here and what's a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: The document type is probably dynamically generated. You could try retrieving the html with `Selenium`.

Comment: @MendelG please put your answer back. Just update the bit about requests. It was a good answer. No harm in showing both ways of getting it. I should have phrased my comment as such.

Comment: @MendelG please repost. Your answer was excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the sitemap and glob just the tar files from that.

https://www.adb.org/sitemap.xml?page=1

[image]

Comment: OMG! I didn't even know what a sitemap was. Thanks!

Comment: My initial solution was to go page by page and pick up links with  "-tar" in it but then I realized that the naming isn't consistent and there were many files which were actual Technical Assistance Reports (as mentioned under Document Type) but their links didnt have "-tar". That's why I was trying to read that portion of the table for my second approach.